# Python 3 Exception in thread ptvsd.stopping (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-2.x

I am new to programming.
I wrote a binary search recursive function. When I run the program using debug I get the correct output but when the debug is OFF, I get the correct answer along with this error:

```
Exception in thread ptvsd. stopping
```

(most likely raised during interpreter shutdown) for some parameters (when x= 8 I get this error but when x = 2 I don't get the error).
I can't understand why I am getting this error.

```
def binary_search_recursive(A, x, low=0, high=None):
    if high is None:
        high = len(A) - 1
    if x == A[low]: return low
    if x == A[high]: return high

    if low == high: return -1
    middle = low + (high - low) / 2
    if x == A[middle]:
        return middle;
    elif x < A[middle]:
        return binary_search_recursive(A, x, low, middle-1)
    elif x > A[middle]:
        return binary_search_recursive(A, x, middle+1, high)

print(binary_search_recursive((2,4,5,6,7,8,10),8))
```

To debug I just place a breakpoint on my print statement using VS code before running the code.

Comment: The formatting of the code looks wrong as the code in the function needs to be indented. It is therefore not possible to see where the function ends. Please edit. Also, it would be good to add some more information: How do you run this with and without debug (presumably from the terminal, but using which command?)

Comment: Done the changes.

Comment: Thanks. The code runs cleanly in python2. The error message is from VS Code. I have never worked with VS Code and am therefore uncertain what it means and why it occurs.  With the added visual-studio-code tag, I hope, someone with more experience with this software will come across this question.